# Python Pandas error and exception handling

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to handle execption/errors with pandas module pd.read_html? What if the HTML is empty or it doesn't have a table how could I manage that? Thanks

Comment: That should throw a very specific error, so why not `try: pd.read_html` and do whatever you want with the `except ThatSpecificError:`?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest [try/except](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) block should do the job:

```
 import pandas
 url = 'http://example.com'
 try:     
     page = pandas.read_html(url, attrs={}, header = 0)
 except Exception as e:
     print(type(e), e)
```

Knowing what exception your code raises you can add more specific handling like:

```
 import pandas
 url = 'http://example.com'
 try:     
     page = pandas.read_html(url, attrs={}, header = 0)
 except YourSpecificException as e:
     # handle YourSpecificException
 except Exception as e:
     # handle all other exceptions
```

Comment: Can this handle XMLSyntaxError and/or a completely empty HTML page (without tags, body and so on)? My goal is to handle this errors, that in my specific case is fine, and move to the next url. Many thanks!

Comment: Yes - just use simple python [error handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Comment: I tried this approach before it didn't work, even though I did create a class user-defined exceptions